# Passing a value in the URL value not showing on the receiving php page

Tags: php, url

this is the code used to get the information from the database, the images I have taken off the echo statement for the time being, and just the name of the product. When I click on the product name it sends me to cart.php and should pass the value in the URL it shows in the browser when I hover over the text but when i click it send me to cart.php and just shows a blank page

```
$product_types = get_all_subjects2();

while($products = mysql_fetch_array($product_types))
{
    $name = $products['name'];
    $address = $products['image_location'];
    $description = $products['description'];
    //echo $name;

    echo '<ul>';
    echo "<li><a href=\"http://localhost/project/cart.php?subj="  . urlencode($products["name"]) . 
        "\">{$products["name"]}</a></li>";
```

the code used to see if value isset

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subj']))
{

    $a = $_POST['subj'];
    echo $a;
}

 else {
            echo"error";
         }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameters passed via URL are in [`$_GET`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.get) and not in [`$_POST`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.post):

> **$_GET**
>
> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

`$_POST` is only for parameters passed by HTTP POST method.

So try `$_GET['subj']` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking the PHP $_POST but are sending the data through URL.

If you're sending information through the URL you need to get at it through $_GET

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['subj'])) {
    $a = $_GET['subj'];
    echo $a;
} else {
     echo"error";
}         
?>
```